# Insert cloned elements in just one query

Tags: php, mysql

I make a cloned element from the original, also increase the name value like this:

Original
 name="UM"

Cloned elements
     name="UM1"
    name="UM2"
     name="UM3"

And I need to insert the data from that cloned elements, I thought make like this:

```
$UM1    = $_POST['UM1'];
$DS1    = $_POST['DS1'];                

$Cant1  = $_POST['Cant1'];                  

$FU1    = $_POST['FU1'];



$query = 'INSERT INTO TABLE 
VALUES (\''.$UM1.'\',\''.$DS1.'\',\''.$Cant1.'\',\''.$FU1.'\')';

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

With every element, but is so much code, exist any way to make this diferent, something like the css selectors `select[id^="UM"]`?

Many Thanks.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MetCastle/aN37B/)

Solution:

```
$rows = array();
$i = 1;
while (isset($_POST["UM$i"])) {
  $rows[] = array($_POST["UM$i"], $_POST["DS$i"], $_POST["Cant$i"], $_POST["FU$i"]);
  $i++;
}

foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $query = 'INSERT INTO papeleria (id, UM, DS, Cant, FU) VALUES ("","'.$row[0].'","'.$row[1].'","'.$row[2].'","'.$row[3].'")';
  mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a for loop

```
$rows = array();
$i = 1;
while (isset($_POST["UM$i"])) {
  $rows[] = array($_POST["UM$i"], $_POST["DS$i"], $_POST["Cant$1"], $_POST["FU$1"]);
  $i++;
}

foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $query = "insert into table values ('$row[0]', '$row[1]', '$row[2]', '$row[3]')";
  mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Hey, many thanks! Now works like a charm. just I changed the number 1 in your line for i and add some quotes in the query, again thanks !
I edited the question with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no such method but you dont need to escape the ' .

```
$query = "INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('$UM1','$DS1','$Cant1','$FU1')";
```

this should work perfectly